# Bundling SCSS files into CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, sass, bundle, integrate

I am trying to Integrate scss file in Asp.Net with the Bundle method:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
"~/Content/css/bootstrap.css","~/Content/css/Site.css"));

var sassBundle = new Bundle("~/content/style-bundle").Include(
"~/content/css/style.scss" );
sassBundle.Transforms.Add(new BundleTransformer.Core.Transformers.CssTransformer());
sassBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
sassBundle.Orderer = new BundleTransformer.Core.Orderers.NullOrderer();
bundles.Add(sassBundle);
 }
}
```

I get the following Error:

```
An exception of type 'BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.AssetTranslationException' occurred in BundleTransformer.SassAndScss.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: During translation of SCSS-code, readed from the file '/content/css/style.scss', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred.

See more details:

```
Message: Undefined mixin 'box-shadow'.

File: /content/css/covve/_colours.scss

Line number: 56
```

I have already download all the Sass lib.Can anyone help me i'm a newbie on sass files.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file containing the `box-shadow` mixin has been imported into the file you are processing as described [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import).